# How do I do string manipulation in an nginx config file?

Tags: php, nginx

I need to manipulate the $request_uri variable in the nginx config file.
In PHP, I would use:

```
join('/', str_split($request_uri, 200))
```

How do I do the same in the nginx config language?

---

#### Context:

I have a URL that's very long. Longer than 255 characters.
The contents of this URL need to be cached in a file, which will then be served by nginx. Linux doesn't really support filenames longer than 255 characters, unless we put in a significant amount of work.

I have opted to split the "path + query string" of the URL into chunks of 200 bytes each, then create a directory for each chunk. In the end, the actual HTML is stored in "index.html" in the last directory of the path.

A simplified example (splitting at 4 bytes, for simplicity). The contents of this URL:

```
example.com/somelongurl
```

will be placed in this file:

```
$CACHE_ROOT/some/long/url/index.html
```

I want to serve this file straight from nginx - without using PHP, Python, or any CGI at all.

Comment: Where this file comes from?

Comment: You're saying that you're *placing* data in a file, not serving the file.  I understand you're expecting some kind of `POST` request to a long URL and then saving the contents to a file.  In that case that is work for `PHP` (or whatever other framework you might use) and a database.  `nginx` is a webserver, it is not meant to use the filesystem as a database; even if there is a clever way to perform this, it is likely to be slow.

Comment: You run the PHP/Python/whatever, then save the HTML in a file. The second requests with the same URL gets served the HTML without delegating to fcgi.

Flat HTML caching for pages that don't change every time... is a popular solution to the performance problem.

I would appreciate it if you consider that the questions is based on understanding how the stack works, and I'm not misusing any of th ecomponents.

The request is a GET.